# GUIDE figure as a function

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I want to write a GUIDE window in MATLAB so that I can it as a function and get the calculations I performed there.

For example: suppose I have a GUIDE figure called `message_ui` containing an edit and a button. when I press this button, I want the figure to return the text in the edit. I want to call this window on a `main` function and get the message in the edit. How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this: https://github.com/ishiikurisu/Lab/tree/master/src/tests/uianswer

Basically, I wait for an user response; the resume the UI on the button press. Then I set the UI's output on the UI_OutputFcn.